# Flutter how to invoke initState() properly

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate, sqflite, loaddata

Hi IM trying to load initial data from db and sharepref as user first open page.

```
...
 List questionsList = [];
 bool _languageA = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    loadData(); // seting for some dropdown menu
    _getLanguageChoise(); //geting from sharepref bool value

    _getData(arabic: _languageArabic).then((value) {   //async db call load List ext...
      setState(() {});
    });
  }
```

Problem is that "questionsList" and "_languageA" bool is not filed in initState , so I get null or initial value, only when I refresh state or reload
List get filed and var get value... So what I need to do in order to have initial filed variables before build method so user can see..

Answer (score 1):

assign questionsList and _languageA values inside initState method just like this in order to initialize a field value when the widget is created

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    questionsList=["hello"];
    _languageA=true;

    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your initstate like this

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
      
questionsList=[""];
_languageA=true;
    loadData(); // seting for some dropdown menu
    _getLanguageChoise(); //geting from sharepref bool value

    _getData(arabic: _languageArabic).then((value) {   //async db call load List ext...
      setState(() {});
    });
  }
```